# How to add sql data to table but not override it?

Tags: php, mysql

I am creating a webapp where people can add data. For ex: I have First Name and Last Name. I want to update a user's account, however I do NOT want to delete that user's old data (old_name, old_lastname, old_email, etc). Instead I want to keep the user's old data and just create a new record. Then I need to access them to show all the old names they used.

From what I found i need to add a time stamp, but i can not find an example. If someone could show me the code to add to my current page that would help me a lot.

once I am able to add the records instead of updating them I will add lot more fields.

Here is my account page :

```
<?php
    include 'header.php';

    session_start();

    //kick none users off the page
    if(isset($_SESSION["UserID"])) {

    }
    else {
        header('Location:login.php');
    }

    //Display the user info
    $user = $_SESSION[UserID];

    $results = $con->query("select * from users where UserID='$user'");

    $row = $results->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH);

    session_start();

    $_SESSION["FirstName"] = $row['FirstName'];
    $_SESSION["LastName"] = $row['LastName'];
    $_SESSION["Email"] = $row['Email'];
    $_SESSION["Password"] = $row['Password'];

    //update user info
    if(isset($_POST['update'])){

        $UpdateFN = $_POST['First_Name'];
        $UpdateLN = $_POST['Last_Name'];
        $UpdateEM = $_POST['Email'];
        $UpdatePW = $_POST['Password'];

        $StorePassword = password_hash($UpdatePW, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, array('cost' => 10));

        $sql = $con->query("UPDATE users SET FirstName = '{$UpdateFN}', LastName = '{$UpdateLN}', Email = '{$UpdateEM}', Password = '{$StorePassword}' where UserID=$user");

        header('Location:account.php');
    }

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Your account</p>
        <?php echo $_SESSION[UserID]; ?><br />
        <a href="logout.php">Logout</a>



        <form action="" method="post" name="AccountForm" id="AccountForm" >
            <input type="text" name="First_Name" placeholder="First Name" id="First_Name" required="required" value="<?php echo $_SESSION["FirstName"]?>"><br>
            <input type="text" name="Last_Name" placeholder="Last Name" id="Last_Name" required="required" value="<?php echo $_SESSION["LastName"]?>"><br>
            <input type="text" name="Email" placeholder="Email" id="Email" required="required" value="<?php echo $_SESSION["Email"]?>"><br>
            <input type="password" name="Password" placeholder="Password" id="Password" required="required" value="<?php echo $_SESSION["Password"]?>"><br><br>
            <input name="update" type="submit" value="Update">
        </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

If I uderstand your objective correctly, You want to keep the log trail of your changes to the record/tuple instance.

One way to do that, is to create a new record in the update trigger, the table schema should only contain the log trail with the Primary key of the original table as foreign key here.

Hope this helps!! Happy to help further